# White gap at the bottom of web page

Tags: html, css

There's this little white gap at the end of my document. I right click and inspect the element and it says it's the body. Any idea how to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

If you don't need border you may add third rule (one of):

```
border-width: 0px;
border: none;
```

If you need to remove only this on down of the screen, use:

```
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
```

This won't even touch this on left or right.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your css:

```
html, body{
   height:100%;
}
```