# White gap at the side of website

Tags: html, css

I had the same issue at the bottom, but this resolved it [White gap at the bottom of web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512254/white-gap-at-the-bottom-of-web-page/33512343#33512343)

I tried doing the same thing for the right but nothing happens.

It seems to only happen at a certain window width.

[image: side gap image example]

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, JS, jsfiddle and etc). Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you want to remove the whitespace in the right side of your web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is `width` of your `form` element(`width: 48.821174201%;`).

Solutions:

```
#plans .affiliateSection form
{
    background-color: red;    
    /* Add width:auto;*/    
    width: auto; 
}
```

**OR**

```
#plans .affiliateSection
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3kss8jg/3/)

[image]

Comment: @Dillon Raphael Is that helpful?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a fair amount of bad HTML markup on this page. I would start by fixing the mismatched tags. View source in FireFox and you'll see that it will light up all of the errors in red text. You can hover over the errors and see what the problem is.
2. After you've fixed the HTML markup. You can look into what is causing the white gap to the right of your page. It is due to several elements on the page that are too wide, or have too much margin to the right of them. Use your browsers inspector to find and fix these elements one at a time.